# Updating product actually destroys it

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am new to Rails and was creating a demo web shop app for study. 
I could create the products smoothly, both via rails console and by the url localhost:300/products/new. 
My problem is when I want to update them. 
I have _form.html.erb partial getting rendered both in new.html.erb and edit.html.erb

In /products/id/edit though the button "Update Product" is actually destroying the product instead of updating it

This is the **_form.htlm.erb**:

```
  <%= form_for(@product) do |f| %>
    <% if @product.errors.any? %>
       <div id="error_explanation">
        <h2><%= pluralize(@product.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this product from being saved:</h2>

        <ul>
            <% @product.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
            <li><%= message %></li>
            <% end %>
        </ul>
</div>
<% end %>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
        <div class="field">
                <%= f.label :name %><br>
                <%= f.text_field :name, :class => "input-group input-group-sm" %>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
                <%= f.label :description %><br>
                <%= f.text_area :description %>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
                <%= f.label :image_url %><br>
                <%= f.text_field :image_url %>
        </div>
        <div class="field">
                <%= f.label :color %><br>
                <%= f.text_field :color %>
        </div>
        <div class="actions">
                <%= f.submit %>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

Please tell me if you need more data
Thanks, 
Anna

---

Updat: here below my routes.rb

---

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
resources :products
get 'news/index' => 'news#index', as: :news
get 'store' => 'store#index', as: :store
get 'contact' => 'contact#index', as: :contact
get 'products/edit' => 'products#edit'
get 'products/destroy' => 'products#destroy'
get 'about' => 'about#index', as: :about
get 'landing_page' => 'static_pages#landing_page', as: :landing_page
get 'home/index'
root 'static_pages#landing_page'
resources :orders, only: [:index, :show, :create, :destroy]
```

---

I have pryed in the products_controller and found this:

---

```
# GET /products/1
# GET /products/1.json
 def show
 end
# GET /products/new
 def new
    @product = Product.new
 end

 # GET /products/1/edit
 def edit
 end

 # POST /products
 # POST /products.json
 def create
    @product = Product.new(product_params)

   respond_to do |format|
     if @product.save
       format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully created.' }
       format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @product }
     else
       format.html { render :new }
       format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end

# PATCH/PUT /products/1
# PATCH/PUT /products/1.json
 def update
   respond_to do |format|
     if @product.update(product_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @product, notice: 'Product was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @product }
     else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @product.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
     end
   end
 end

# DELETE /products/1
# DELETE /products/1.json
def destroy
  @product.destroy
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to products_url, notice: 'Product was successfully destroyed.' }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  end
end
```

Comment: pry in `update action` and provide your `params`

Comment: Could you include your `routes.rb` in your question?

Comment: @SteveTurczyn: i have added the routes.rb to my question

Comment: @OlegSobchuk: i have added the products_controller.rb as well - does it help you? Thank you in advance to all!

Comment: @Anna no, I need `params` what you get in action. Use `binding.pry` and cause `params`

Comment: `get 'products/destroy' => 'products#destroy'`?!

Comment: @DaveNewton: ops, it's a line I wrote  just for testing and playing around with the routes.rb file, while studying...I just removed it, and saved but the issue is still there though .

Comment: @OlegSobchuk: i am reading the documentation for binding.pry, i will give it a try

Comment: You can also just look at the logs to see the params. First thing is to make sure the correct controller method is being hit, which you can determine from the logs.

Comment: @DaveNewton: thanks Dave! I just "solved" it...(although it is not a real or satisfactory solution)

Comment: the Edit.html.erb had also three options for: Show|Delete|Back
The Delete option was coded with : 
    <%= link_to 'Delete', @product.destroy %> 
I deleted this line and the product got edited instead of being cancelled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Edit.html.erb had also three options for: Show|Delete|Back The Delete option was coded with : <%= link_to 'Delete', @product.destroy %> I deleted this line and the product got edited instead of being cancelled.